# How can I define a type with a generic type in parent/child structure?

Tags: typescript

I want to use a type recursively in all children.

Actually, right now I should do something like this:

`Widget<Widget<Widget<Widget>>> ...`

But I want to use it without any restriction (Just once).

`Widget<Widget>`

```
type Widget<T = string> = {
    children?: T[]
}

const foo: Widget<Widget> = {
    children: [
        {
            // I want to be able to use Widget type here also
            // but it only allow me to use string not WidgetType.
            children: ['A', 'B']
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: I'd like to see more use case examples here.  The type `type DeepWidget<T> = {children?: (T | DeepWidget<T>)[]}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJy9Zm) might suffice, but it's hard to say without concrete examples of what things should work and what things should not.  After all, `Widget<Widget<Widget<Widget<...>>>>>` will *only* accept `Widget`s at all depths and not `string`s at all (equivalent to `DeepWidget<never>`, but your only example seems to use `string`s and doesn't even attempt to nest widgets.

Comment: There is an open discussion which is about behaving generic types as generics themselves: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213 . Which I think would somehow be helpful in your case if implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```js
type Widget<T = string> = {
    children?: T[] | Widget<T>[]
}

const foo: Widget<Widget> = {
    children: [
        {
            children: [
                {
                    children: ['A', 'B']
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKykoN)